# Nested iteration in Rust macros

Tags: rust

I'm playing with macros in Rust and want to do nested expansion, i.e. combinatorics.

This is the code I've written:

```
macro_rules! nested {
    (
        $(arg $arg:ident;)*
        $(fun $fun:ident;)*
    ) => {
        $(
            $fun($($arg),*);
        )*
    }
}

fn show1(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) {
    println!("show1: {} {} {}", a, b, c);
}
fn show2(a: i32, b: i32, c: i32) {
    println!("show2: {} {} {}", a, b, c);
}

fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let c = 3;
    nested! {
        arg a;
        arg b;
        arg c;
        fun show1;
        fun show2;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=cfe3c9d319b9fd2e2cc46abfdcf18eb2&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I want this to expand to

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let c = 3;
    // iteration over $fun
    show1(/* iteration over $arg */a, b, c);
    show2(/* iteration over $arg */a, b, c);
}
```

However, it seems that Rust doesn't support this and instead complains:

```
error: inconsistent lockstep iteration: 'fun' has 2 items, but 'arg' has 3
```

So apparently it ignores the inner iteration.

However, if I remove one of the args, to make it 2 items for both, it still complains:

```
<anon>:7:18: 7:25 error: attempted to repeat an expression containing no
                  syntax variables matched as repeating at this depth
<anon>:7             $fun($($arg),*);
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to do this kind of expansion. Here is a workaround:

```
macro_rules! nested {
    ($(arg $arg:ident;)* $(fun $fun:ident;)*) => {
        // expand arg to a tuple that will be matched as tt
        // in @call_tuple an will be decomposed back to
        // a list of args in @call
        nested!(@call_tuple $($fun),* @ ($($arg),*))
    };
    (@call_tuple $($fun:ident),* @ $tuple:tt) => {
        $(nested!(@call $fun $tuple))*
    };
    (@call $fun:ident ($($arg:expr),*)) => {
        $fun($($arg),*);
    };
}
```

The `@id` is only used to keep the rules [internal](https://danielkeep.github.io/tlborm/book/pat-internal-rules.html) to the macro.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a slightly simpler approach.

```rust
macro_rules! nested {
    (($($f:ident),*) $args:tt) => {
        $(nested!(@call $f $args);)*
    };
    (@call $f:ident ($($arg:expr),*)) => {
        $f($($arg),*);
    };
}

nested! {
    (show1, show2)
    (a, b, c)
}
```

Same principle as @malbarbo's answer but change your macro to put args in parenthesis. Then you can accept the args as a single token so that only the function names are repeated in the first expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can't nest repetitions directly, but you can do it with a second macro invocation. Here I'm expanding all of the args with one repetition, calling back into an internal rule in my macro. The internal rule sees them all together as `combined_args`. It then does the second repetition over the functions.

```rust
macro_rules! nested {
    (@internal $combined_args:tt ; $(fun $fun:ident;)*) => {
        $( $fun$combined_args; )*
    };

    ( $(arg $arg:ident;)* $($funs:tt)* ) => {
        nested!(@internal ($($arg),*) ; $($funs)*)
    };
}
```

...except it doesn't compile because of ambiguity:

```
error: local ambiguity when calling macro `nested`: multiple parsing options: built-in NTs tt ('funs') or 1 other option.
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
23 |         arg a;
   |         ^^^

error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Apparently `macro_rules!` isn't greedy like (e.g.) regular expressions. So now I'll modify it to look for the end or `fun` to disambiguate:

```rust
macro_rules! nested {
    ( @internal $combined_args:tt ; $(fun $fun:ident;)* ) => {
        $( $fun$combined_args; )*
    };

    ( $(arg $arg:ident;)* ) => { };

    ( $(arg $arg:ident;)* fun $($tail:tt)* ) => {
        nested!(@internal ($($arg),*) ; fun $($tail)*)
    };
}
```

This works.

That said, the form [@cambunctious](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2019549/cambunctious) used is easier to handle (because the args are pre-combined) and looks more like a regular function call anyway. `multi_fn_call! { (show1, show2)(a, b, c) }` has a nice ring to it. If you aren't picky about the format of compile errors when the caller doesn't pass the args as expected, you can do it with one repetition in one rule:

```rust
macro_rules! multi_fn_call {
    ( ( $($fn:path),* ) $args:tt ) => { $($fn$args;)* };
}
```